# How to change visibility and textcolor in Kotlin recycleview adapter

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, visibility, textcolor

Visibility and text color are easy to change in fragments and activities, but when I use the same code in an activity, nothing happens. So, how do I programmically change visibility and text color in a Kotlin adapter? Do I make these changes in onBindViewHolder or MyViewHolder.
Note: I was able to do this in a Java adaptor last year.

Here's the code. Look forward to hearing from you.

You all stay safe out there.

---

recycler_list_layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/visible_full_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weight"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minutes"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/colon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/systolic"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diastolic"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/slash"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/slash" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_med10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

...

...

```
class ListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

private var userlist = emptyList<User>()

 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
     return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
         .inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_layout, parent, false)
     )
 }

 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return userlist.size}

 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

     val currentItem = userlist[position]

currentItem.id.toString()
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.date).text = currentItem.date_tv
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.weight).text = currentItem.weight_tv
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.hours).text = currentItem.hour_tv
         //INVISIBLE minutes_tv when empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.minutes).text = 
currentItem.minutes_tv
         //red text color when bg is over 120
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bg).text = currentItem.bg_tv
         //red text color when systolic is over 120
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.systolic).text = 
 currentItem.systolic_tv
         //red text color when diastolic is over 80
         //INVISIBLE diastolic_tv when empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.diastolic).text = 
currentItem.diastolic_tv
         //GONE when med1 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med1).text = currentItem.med1_tv
         //GONE when med2 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med2).text = currentItem.med2_tv
         //GONE when med3 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med3).text = currentItem.med3_tv
         //GONE when med4 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med4).text = currentItem.med4_tv
         //GONE when med5 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med5).text = currentItem.med5_tv
         //GONE when med6 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med6).text = currentItem.med6_tv
         //GONE when med7 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med7).text = currentItem.med7_tv
         //GONE when med8 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med8).text = currentItem.med8_tv
         //GONE when med9 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med9).text = currentItem.med9_tv
        //GONE when med10 is empty
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_med10).text = 
currentItem.med10_tv
     holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.comment).text = 
currentItem.comment_tv

     //not working, change text color
     //NullPointerException
//       bg_tv!!.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F61505"))
//       holder.bg_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorAccent))
//       bg_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorAccent))
//
//       //not working
//       med1_tv.visibility = View.GONE
//       med1_tv.isVisible = false
//       holder.itemView.visibility = View.GONE
//       holder.item_med1!!.visibility = View.GONE

     holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.visible_full_row).setOnClickListener {
//             val context: Context = holder.itemView.context

         val action = HomeFragmentDirections.homeFragmentToEditFragment(currentItem)
         holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
     }
 }

 fun setData(user: List<User>){
     this.userlist = user
     notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
}
```

...

...

```
open class MyViewHolder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

var date: TextView? = null
var weight: TextView? = null
var hours: TextView? = null
var minutes: TextView? = null
var bg: TextView? = null
var systolic: TextView? = null
var diastolic: TextView? = null
var item_med1: TextView? = null
var item_med2: TextView? = null
var item_med3: TextView? = null
var item_med4: TextView? = null
var item_med5: TextView? = null
var item_med6: TextView? = null
var item_med7: TextView? = null
var item_med8: TextView? = null
var item_med9: TextView? = null
var item_med10: TextView? = null
var comment: TextView? = null

fun MyViewHolder(itemView: View) {

    date = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.date) as TextView //recycler_list_layout
    weight = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.weight) as TextView
    hours = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.hours) as TextView
    minutes = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.minutes) as TextView
    bg = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.bg) as TextView
    systolic = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.systolic) as TextView
    diastolic = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.diastolic) as TextView
    item_med1 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med1) as TextView
    item_med2 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med2) as TextView
    item_med3 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med3) as TextView
    item_med4 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med4) as TextView
    item_med5 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med5) as TextView
    item_med6 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med6) as TextView
    item_med7 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med7) as TextView
    item_med8 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med8) as TextView
    item_med9 = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med9) as TextView
    item_med10 =itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.item_med10) as TextView
    comment = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.comment) as TextView

//        Why is it this code works in fragments and activities, yet fails in adapters?
//        Why is it this code worked in java adapters, but not kotlin?

//        //not working
//        if (item_med1!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med1!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med2!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med3!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med4!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med5!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med6!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med7!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med8!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med9!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
//        if (item_med10!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {item_med10!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

//        //not working
//        item_med1!!.visibility = View.GONE
//        item_med1!!.isVisible = false

//         //not working, change text color
//         //NullPointerException
//         bg!!.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F61505"))
//         bg.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorAccent))
//
}
}
```

...

...

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(){

private val myPreference = "myPref"

private val MED1_KEY = "KEY_MED1"
private val MED2_KEY = "KEY_MED2"
private val MED3_KEY = "KEY_MED3"
private val MED4_KEY = "KEY_MED4"
private val MED5_KEY = "KEY_MED5"
private val MED6_KEY = "KEY_MED6"
private val MED7_KEY = "KEY_MED7"
private val MED8_KEY = "KEY_MED8"
private val MED9_KEY = "KEY_MED9"
private val MED10_KEY = "KEY_MED10"

private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

private lateinit var addfloat: FloatingActionButton
private lateinit var Recycler: RecyclerView

private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,

    ): View? {

    homeViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
        container, false)

    val context = activity?.applicationContext

    addfloat = root.findViewById(R.id.fab)
    Recycler = root.findViewById(R.id.product_list)

    val adapter = ListAdapter()
    Recycler.adapter = adapter
    Recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    homeViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        })

    addfloat.setOnClickListener { view ->
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.homeFragment_to_addFragment)
    }

//        //working, changed text color
//        headerTV_med1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent))

    //wrapcontent
    val headerTV_med1 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med1) as TextView
    val headerTV_med2 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med2) as TextView
    val headerTV_med3 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med3) as TextView
    val headerTV_med4 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med4) as TextView
    val headerTV_med5 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med5) as TextView
    val headerTV_med6 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med6) as TextView
    val headerTV_med7 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med7) as TextView
    val headerTV_med8 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med8) as TextView
    val headerTV_med9 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med9) as TextView
    val headerTV_med10 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med10) as TextView

    //50dp
    val headerTV_med1a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med1a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med2a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med2a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med3a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med3a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med4a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med4a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med5a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med5a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med6a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med6a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med7a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med7a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med8a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med8a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med9a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med9a) as TextView
    val headerTV_med10a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med10a) as TextView

    sharedPreferences =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(myPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    //wrapcontente
    headerTV_med1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED1_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED2_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med3.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED3_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med4.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED4_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med5.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED5_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med6.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED6_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med7.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED7_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med8.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED8_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med9.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED9_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med10.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED10_KEY, ""))

    //50dp
    headerTV_med1a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED1_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med2a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED2_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med3a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED3_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med4a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED4_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med5a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED5_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med6a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED6_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med7a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED7_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med8a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED8_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med9a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED9_KEY, ""))
    headerTV_med10a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED10_KEY, ""))

    //this works in fragment, not in adapter
    if (headerTV_med1.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med1.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med2.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med2.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med3.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med3.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med4.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med4.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med5.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med5.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med6.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med6.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med7.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med7.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med8.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med8.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med9.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med9.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    if (headerTV_med10.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med10.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    //meds will be truncated in 50dp TextViews
    //onClickListener will GONE the 50dp TextViews and VISIBLE the wrapcontent TextViews
    //onFocusListener might work better
    headerTV_med1.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med1.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med1a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med1a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med1a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med1.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med2.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med2.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med2a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med2a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med2a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med2.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med3.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med3.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med3a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med3a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med3a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med3.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med4.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med4.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med4a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med4a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med4a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med4.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med5.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med5.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med5a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med5a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med5a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med5.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med6.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med6.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med6a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med6a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med6a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med6.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med7.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med7.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med7a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med7a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med7a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med7.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med8.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med8.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med8a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med8a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med8a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med8.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med9.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med9.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med9a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med9a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med9a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med9.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    headerTV_med10.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med10.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med10a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
    headerTV_med10a.setOnClickListener {
        headerTV_med10a.visibility = View.GONE
        headerTV_med10.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

    return root
}
}
```

...

...

```
class HomeViewModel (application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>>
private val repository: UserRepository
init {
    val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
    repository = UserRepository(userDao)
    readAllData = repository.readAllData
}

fun addUser(user: User){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.addUser(user)
    }
}

fun upDateData(user: User){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.upDateData(user)
    }
}

fun deleteData(user: User){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteData(user)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at some `RecyclerView` tutorials and read about what the `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` methods do. The documentation explains everything in much more detail than an answer here can. Here for example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter.

Comment: Have done and will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the code to work by implementing databinding.

Recommend the following codelabs to get you started on room, recyclerview and databinding.

codelabs

```
TrackMySleepQuality
   6.1, 6.2, and 6.3
RecyclerView
   7.1, 7.2 up to Task 6, Step 3: Replace findViewById()
```

Couldn't get past 7.2, Task 6, Step 3: Replace findViewById() without breaking the project.

Here is the new code.

Adapter

```
   package com.example.kotlindrawer.adapters
   
   import android.graphics.Color
   import android.view.LayoutInflater
   import android.view.View
   import android.view.ViewGroup
   import android.widget.LinearLayout
   import android.widget.TextView
   import androidx.navigation.findNavController
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.R
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.models.User
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.ui.home.HomeFragmentDirections
   
   class UserAdapter : ListAdapter<User, UserAdapter.ViewHolder>(UserDiffCallback())                      {//7.2.2
       override fun onBindViewHolder( holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {//7.1.2
           val item = getItem(position)//7.2.2
           bind(holder, item)//7.1.2
       }

       private fun bind( holder: ViewHolder, item: User) {
   
           //needed to display data//7.2.2
           holder.adapterdate.text = item.date_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterweight.text = item.weight_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterhours.text = item.hour_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptercolon.text = item.colon_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterminutes.text = item.minutes_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterbg.text = item.bg_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptersystolic.text = item.systolic_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterslash.text = item.slash_tv.toString()
           holder.adapterdiastolic.text = item.diastolic_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed1.text = item.med1_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed2.text = item.med2_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed3.text = item.med3_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed4.text = item.med4_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed5.text = item.med5_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed6.text = item.med6_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed7.text = item.med7_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed8.text = item.med8_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed9.text = item.med9_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptermed10.text = item.med10_tv.toString()
           holder.adaptercomment.text = item.comment_tv.toString()
   
   //the following code did not work until databinding
   
           //this code will print values red when
           // blood glucose, systolic and diastolic are high
           try {
               val b: Int = holder.adapterbg.getText().toString().toInt()
               if (b > 120) {holder.adapterbg.setTextColor(Color.RED)
               }
           } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
               println("Could not parse $nfe")
           }
   
           try {
               val b: Int = holder.adaptersystolic.getText().toString().toInt()
               if (b > 120) {holder.adaptersystolic.setTextColor(Color.RED)
               }
           } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
               println("Could not parse $nfe")
           }
   
           try {
               val b: Int = holder.adapterdiastolic.getText().toString().toInt()
               if (b > 80) {holder.adapterdiastolic.setTextColor(Color.RED)
               }
           } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
               println("Could not parse $nfe")
           }
   
           //this invisibles colon and slash TextViews when values are blank
           if (holder.adapterminutes.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptercolon.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}
           if (holder.adapterdiastolic.text.isBlank()) {holder.adapterslash.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}
   
           //this gones empty medication TextViews
           if (holder.adaptermed1.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed1.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed2.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed2.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed3.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed3.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed4.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed4.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed5.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed5.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed6.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed6.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed7.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed7.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed8.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed8.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed9.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed9.visibility = View.GONE}
           if (holder.adaptermed10.text.isBlank()) {holder.adaptermed10.visibility = View.GONE}
   
           holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.visible_full_row)
        .setOnClickListener {
               val action = HomeFragmentDirections.homeFragmentToEditFragment(item)
               holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
           }
       }
   
       override fun onCreateViewHolder(
           parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {//7.1.2
           return ViewHolder.from(parent)
       }
   
       class ViewHolder private constructor(
           itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
   
           //needed for fun bind
           //how to get rid of this
           val adapterdate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date)
           val adapterweight: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_weight)
           val adapterhours: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_hours)
           val adaptercolon: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_colon)
           val adapterminutes: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_minutes)
           val adapterbg: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bg)
           val adaptersystolic: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_systolic)
           val adapterslash: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_slash)
           val adapterdiastolic: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_diastolic)
           val adaptermed1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med1)
           val adaptermed2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med2)
           val adaptermed3: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med3)
           val adaptermed4: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med4)
           val adaptermed5: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med5)
           val adaptermed6: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med6)
           val aaptermed7: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med7)
           val adaptermed8: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med8)
           val adaptermed9: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med9)
           val adaptermed10: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_med10)
           val adaptercomment: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_comment)
   
           fun bind(item: User){ }
   
           companion object {
               fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                   val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater
                       .from(parent.context)
   
                   val view = layoutInflater
                       .inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_layout,
                           parent, false)//7.1.2
   
                   return ViewHolder(view)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   
   class UserDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {//7.2.1
       override fun areContentsTheSame(
           oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {//7.2.1
           return oldItem == newItem//7.2.1
       }//7.2.1
   
       override fun areItemsTheSame(
           oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean {//7.2.1
           return oldItem.stat_id == newItem.stat_id//7.2.1
       }//7.2.1
   }//7.2.1
```

...

HomeFragment

...

```
   package com.example.kotlindrawer.ui.home
   
   //TODO try onFocusListener, replace onClickListener
   //TODO replace sharedpreferences with datastore
   //TODO try binding to share data from Medications fragment
   
   import android.content.Context
   import android.content.SharedPreferences
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.view.LayoutInflater
   import android.view.View
   import android.view.ViewGroup
   import android.widget.TextView
   import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
   import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
   import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
   import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
   import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.R
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.Room.UserDatabase
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.adapters.UserAdapter
   import com.example.kotlindrawer.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
   import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
   
   class HomeFragment : Fragment(){
   
       private val myPreference = "myPref"
   
       private val MED1_KEY = "KEY_MED1"
       private val MED2_KEY = "KEY_MED2"
       private val MED3_KEY = "KEY_MED3"
       private val MED4_KEY = "KEY_MED4"
       private val MED5_KEY = "KEY_MED5"
       private val MED6_KEY = "KEY_MED6"
       private val MED7_KEY = "KEY_MED7"
       private val MED8_KEY = "KEY_MED8"
       private val MED9_KEY = "KEY_MED9"
       private val MED10_KEY = "KEY_MED10"
   
       private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
   
       private lateinit var addfloat: FloatingActionButton
   
       // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
       // onDestroyView.
   
       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
           container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?,): View? {
   
           // Get a reference to the binding object and inflate the fragment        views.//SleepTracker
           val binding: FragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(//SleepTracker
               inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)//SleepTracker
   
           val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application//SleepTracker
   
           val dataSource = UserDatabase.getInstance(application).userDao()//SleepTracker
   
           val viewModelFactory = HomeViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)//SleepTracker
   
           val homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)//5.3
               .get(HomeViewModel::class.java)//5.3
   
           binding.homeViewModel = homeViewModel//5.3
   
           binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner//5.3
   
           val adapter = UserAdapter()//7.1
           binding.productList.adapter = adapter//7.1
   
           val nights = dataSource.getAllNights()//7.1
   
           homeViewModel.nights.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {//7.1.1
               it?.let {//7.1.1
                   adapter.submitList(it)//7.2.2
               }//7.1.1
           })//7.1.1
   
           val root: View = binding.root
   
           addfloat = root.findViewById(R.id.fab)
           addfloat.setOnClickListener {
               findNavController().navigate(R.id.homeFragment_to_addFragment)
           }
   
           //wrapcontent
           val headerTV_med1 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med1) as TextView
           val headerTV_med2 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med2) as TextView
           val headerTV_med3 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med3) as TextView
           val headerTV_med4 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med4) as TextView
           val headerTV_med5 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med5) as TextView
           val headerTV_med6 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med6) as TextView
           val headerTV_med7 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med7) as TextView
           val headerTV_med8 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med8) as TextView
           val headerTV_med9 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med9) as TextView
           val headerTV_med10 = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med10) as TextView
   
           //50dp
           val headerTV_med1a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med1a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med2a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med2a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med3a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med3a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med4a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med4a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med5a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med5a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med6a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med6a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med7a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med7a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med8a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med8a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med9a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med9a) as TextView
           val headerTV_med10a = root.findViewById(R.id.headerTV_med10a) as TextView
   
           sharedPreferences =
               requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(myPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

           //VISIBLEs TextViews with content
           if (haderTV_med1.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med1.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med2.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med2.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med3.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med3.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med4.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med4.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med5.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med5.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med6.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med6.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med7.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med7.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med8.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med8.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med9.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med9.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           if (headerTV_med10.text.isNotEmpty()) {headerTV_med10.visibility = View.VISIBLE}

           //wrapcontents
           headerTV_med1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED1_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED2_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med3.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED3_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med4.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED4_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med5.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED5_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med6.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED6_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med7.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED7_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med8.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED8_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med9.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED9_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med10.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED10_KEY, ""))
   
           //50dp
           headerTV_med1a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED1_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med2a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED2_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med3a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED3_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med4a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED4_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med5a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED5_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med6a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED6_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med7a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED7_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med8a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED8_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med9a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED9_KEY, ""))
           headerTV_med10a.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MED10_KEY, ""))
   
           //meds will be truncated in 50dp TextViews
           //onClickListener will GONE the 50dp TextViews and VISIBLE the wrapcontent TextViews
           //onFocusListener might work better
           headerTV_med1.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med1.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med1a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med1a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med1a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med1.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med2.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med2.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med2a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med2a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med2a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med2.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med3.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med3.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med3a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med3a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med3a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med3.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med4.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med4.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med4a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med4a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med4a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med4.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med5.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med5.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med5a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med5a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med5a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med5.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med6.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med6.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med6a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med6a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med6a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med6.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med7.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med7.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med7a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med7a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med7a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med7.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med8.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med8.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med8a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med8a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med8a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med8.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med9.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med9.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med9a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med9a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med9a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med9.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           headerTV_med10.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med10.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med10a.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
           headerTV_med10a.setOnClickListener {
           headerTV_med10a.visibility = View.GONE
           headerTV_med10.visibility = View.VISIBLE}
   
           return binding.root//7.1.1       
       }
   }
```

...

Well folks, the snow has melted and the frost advisories have faded into memory.
Time to leave the computer behind and get my hands dirty in the garden.
Next winter, maybe I can finish the codelab with this project. Then, maybe, DataStore...